# Classic ASP Email Notification with loop functions

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I'll appreciate any assistance on this. The scenario;

I have a database table with the following sample records;

```
data1-------------dt2----data3------data4--------data5------data6  
Brewing Plant-----2------10000------11/3/2012----1136-------person1@yahoo.com  
Brewing Plant-----2------10000------11/3/2012----1136-------person1@yahoo.com  
Car Plant---------1------5000-------11/3/2012----568--------person1@yahoo.com  
Brewing Plant-----1------5000-------11/3/2012----568--------person2@yahoo.com  
Car Plant---------4------20000------11/3/2012----2272-------person2@yahoo.com  
Brewing Plant-----3------15000------11/3/2012----1704-------person3@yahoo.com
```

This is my requirement:
I want just one notification email each sent to theses various persons with their information. If you notice, some summations are done before the email is sent to each individual e.g;

Person1 should receive an email like

```
Data1-----------dt2---data5  
Brewing Plant---4-----2272  
Car Plant-------1-----568
```

while Person2 should receive an email like

```
Data1-----------dt2---data5  
Brewing Plant---1-----568  
Car Plant-------4-----2272
```

and so on.

I am using classic ASP and mySQL

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I think your query is ok. There might be something wrong in your loop. put some codes

Answer (score 0):

You just need to group your table by person and use [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregation as appropriate:

```
SELECT   data6, data1, SUM(dt2), SUM(data5)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY data6, data1
ORDER BY data6
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dca4/1/0).

Then loop over the resultset in your application code, keeping track of when `data6` differs from the last record seen.